# Can't see anything while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, usb, system-installation

I've been using Ubuntu 12 in my laptop but now I have a new compuer and I'm trying to install Ubuntu(or GNOME) 14.04 LTS but I can't.

I put the ISO file with "Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.8" into my pendrive, all goes well, but When I reboot the computer and boots into UBUNTU install menu from pendrive(where I have options to try, install, check memory, etc) and when I try to install ubuntu it only shows a gray screen and then I have a message in my LCD that says "frecuencies out of range", so I decided to try some commands like: vga=771, nomodeset, acpi=off and others that I found here, but with all these commands I see "ubuntu" and the points un red and white but nothing happens, after that I got the same message "out of range" anyone can tell me how to install it?

My computer:

AMD Bulldozer FX-6300(black ed)
8GB RAM
GT-9800 Nvidia 1GB
17" monitor
500GB HDD

Regards,
Juan Pablo

Comment: Have you tried unetbootin or usb-creator-gtk? I've never had any problems with those 2...

Comment: I can install it with network installer, but now I can access to desktop :( I donwloaded Ubuntu Desktop but I see the black screen I want to cry

Comment: You seem to have a lot of trouble to install Ubuntu and it seems video-related, so why not 
1/ disable NVidia in the BIOS and install Ubuntu.  If that works, get back to me.
 *OR* 
2/ start with Lubuntu (internally it's the same OS) and then upgrade to Ubuntu from there (at least you'll have something to fall back to)

Comment: @Fabby okay, how to disable Nvidia? My motherboard have Integrated ATI Radeon HD 3000 graphics so I have to use it? and whats the difference with LUBUNTU?

Comment: How did the new LCD work out???

Comment: Nothing happens, I have the same problem, I think that the problem is The video Card, Can I try to install ubuntu with the EXE file that is on the pendrive? EDIT: I installed Windows 7 for now

Comment: I have no clue any more...  I've upvoted your question to try and attract more skilled people then me...  Sorry. :-(

Comment: @Fabby anway, thanks, maybe this thread help others, and with your help I know Lubuntu and other commands, I'll try to put Xubuntu in my laptop, and then clone it to my desktop PC